# Best practices for custom http user-agent strings?

Tags: web-services, http, user-agent

I'm developing an application that communicates with an internal web service using HTTP.

Are there any "best practices" for custom user-agent strings so that I can put a nice one in my app? It's a Python library and the lower transport is Python's own httplib. Should the user-agent string say that or something else?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For internal use you can use anything really.

Of course, internal or external its always a good idea to include contact information, either web or email address, in case something breaks or application goes out of control.

Check this big list of user agents for inspiration: https://user-agents.net/

Comment: Say a service is sending requests (something like a push notification), would you set user-agent to describe the service or rather the environment the service is running on? Whats more expected?

Comment: that entire website is forbidden.

Comment: Looks like it has been moved to https://user-agents.net/

Answer (score 0):

It is considered good practice to include at least an email address so people can contact you if your application is causing problems. This will also be your best chance of not getting blocked.

It's common to put a name and version number as well. Other than that it's mostly freestyle. [user-agents.org](http://www.user-agents.org) has alot of examples.

Don't forget to honor [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can write in user-agent what you want! But if you beware of your application HTTP queries to this server may be blocked, set user-agent to common browser (like Firefox on Gecko engine) then server admin don't know what application reads her page and in server logs don't see your application.

Comment: Bad practice. Bots must be polite.